# String Comparison in Batch Not Working

Tags: string, batch-file, compare

This has been frustrating me for TOO long. It can't be this hard. I've been looking at other people's examples and STILL cannot get two strings to match up in Batch. What am I doing wrong?

```
SET largeString="c:\programs\test"
SET compareTo="test"
SET smallString=%largeString:~13,4%
if %compareTo%==%smallString% echo YES
```

So that's literally ALL I'm trying to do. It will never echo YES. I have tried

```
if "%compareTo%"=="%smallString%"
```

And

```
if %compareTo% EQU %smallString%
```

And

```
if "%compareTo%" EQU "%smallString%"
```

I am so frustrated at this x.x Did I miss a space somewhere? Did I add a space somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your quotations are a literal part of the `largeString` and `compareTo` strings, therefore your sub-string numbers are wrong and the quotations are included in the comparison from the compareTo string.

NOTE: OP updated answer, with new numbers.

Comment: Ah! I see. So I changed compareTo to equal just test (not "test") and the comparison worked.
Thank you very much!